# Bathroom Faucet Cartridge is Seized. How to remove this?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, bathroom-fixtures, cartridge

I have a leaky bathroom faucet (single handle) where I am trying to replace the cartridge. In the process, I broke the cartridge in half as it turns out the cartridge is stuck to the faucet. Does anyone have any tips for removing the remaining part of the cartridge from the faucet?

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: put a screw in it so you have something to pull on

Comment: Some vinegar pour in and left sit for a few minutes won't hurt either.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you got the cartridge out. That is the plastic part in your hand and the ceramic disc and "O" rings on the counter. The 3 openings in the faucet should be the hot and cold supply and the mixing opening. It appears that needs the calcium deposits cleaned out, then you are good to install the new cartridge.

Comment: the replacement part looks like this (https://www.amazon.ca/American-Standard-M951472-0070A-INTERCHANGE-CARTRIDGE/dp/B00D5Z3CTI) so it appears I only pulled the top part of the cartridge out. The part below the blue part is firmly stuck...

Comment: If the faucet you are trying to repair is a single handle model, the part you found on Amazon is incorrect.  For a single handle faucet the cartridge must have 3 ports not 2.

Comment: Please show a pic on the numbers on the old cartridge so we may be able to help match it up.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a model number on the cartridge. All I found was maybe a serial number '190169' on the side. I posted a pic up top.